# Pom.xml not importing selenium

Tags: java, visual-studio, maven, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to import the java selenium libraries however, I am receiving this issue:

> [Java] package org.openqa.selenium.chrome does not exist

And in my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>javafx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
    <version>javafx</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>      
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                            <version>8.10</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.github.ngeor</groupId>
                            <artifactId>checkstyle-rules</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <configLocation>com/github/ngeor/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                        <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                You can run jacoco in the default profile with:
                mvn jacoco:prepare-agent test jacoco:report
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>com/github/ngeor/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <profiles>
        <!--
        This profile enables jacoco when unit tests are run.
        You can run it with mvn -P jacoco test.
        It also activates itself on Travis.
        -->
        <profile>
            <id>jacoco</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.TRAVIS</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>prepare-agent</id>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>report</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <!--
        For the Travis profile:
        - we want to break the build on any checkstyle violation.
        - we want to be able to publish coverage report to coveralls.
        -->
        <profile>
            <id>travis</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.TRAVIS</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>checkstyle</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>check</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eluder.coveralls</groupId>
                        <artifactId>coveralls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>4.3.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I am using Visual Studio code and I keep updating the pom.xml file. However, I am still unable to make my java file recognize selenium. I extracted the dependency code directly from the website and put it under the `<dependencies>` tag.

Comment: just clean the repository [delete files related to the things downloaded by maven] and try again `mvn clean install`. Try to use some IDE which can clearly explain the issues in setting up...  [Note : Also check whether setting.xml of maven is correctly linked with Visual Code]

Answer (score 1):

just clean the repository [delete files related to the things downloaded by maven] and try again `mvn clean install`. Try to use some IDE which can clearly explain the issues in setting up... [Note : Also check whether setting.xml of maven is correctly linked with Visual Code]

Comment: I'm getting this error I get when I clean install https://pastebin.com/raw/zaDuZJgZ

Comment: try this fix.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025337/fixing-error-unreported-exception-interruptedexception. further you are deviating from the question. better updated the question for other people to clearly understand issues.

Comment: I just commented out the code that was causing that issue, and I ran `mvn clean install` again and it said everything built properly however, I still cannot use the imports for selenium in my code.

Comment: have you setup, the setting.xml for maven and are you sure are there any issues in downloading because of proxy...  in worst case try reinstall maven and setup them back try build again. this occurs actually because of some invalid version issues not the issues mention. first check for network connection and try the second.

Comment: And also restart your system.

Comment: I just put log4j dependencies in my pom.xml file and the import statement was valid, and when I took out log4j dependencies, the import statement became invalid. Which means that my maven is able to properly import dependencies. Could it be that the selenium dependency is not working? Also I restarted my computer and the issue still persists.

Comment: ` <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency> ` try some older version, btw that wont be actually an issue. i said restarted since it may not actually synced. if you have intelliej idea you can clearly view the actual status of dependencies. I am not sure about how visual code display that

Comment: I just opened up my project in eclipse that is using selenium and its giving no errors in the import statement however, in visual studio code it is. There seems to be a problem with my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You POM is correct . I am able to import dependencies from eclipse using shared pom.

Comment: package org.openqa.selenium.chrome  is there in selenium-chrome-driver-3.14.0.jar downloaded.

Comment: Ya I do not understand why Visual Studio Code is not importing the dependencies.